# Laravel 5.1 - Commands not running as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I have some commands that run with the scheduler, some of them are not working as expected, the code works fine if placed in an external file. but when ran as a command with the scheduler it doesn't do anything, no files are deleted & there is no output from the file.

Command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DirectoryIterator;

class CleanExports extends Command {

    protected $name = 'clean:exports';

    public function fire() {
$folderName = 'exports';

if (file_exists($folderName)) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($folderName) as $fileInfo) {
        if ($fileInfo->isDot()) {
        continue;
        }
        if (time() - $fileInfo->getCTime() >= 1*24*60*60) {
            unlink($fileInfo->getRealPath());
        }
        $i++;
    }

    echo $i.' files cleaned';
}        
}
}
```

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;    

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;    

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
        '\App\Console\Commands\CleanExports',
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
        $schedule->command('inspire')
                ->hourly();    
             $schedule->command('clean:exports')->everyMinute()->sendOutputTo('temp/errors.txt');
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does it no delete the files? Be more specific.

Comment: What kinda of "scheduler" do you use for your jobs?

Comment: and this line in `kernel.php` `\App\Console\Commands\CleanExports::class` instead of this `'\App\Console\Commands\CleanExports'`

Comment: Is the exports directory inside you laravel application? If so where is it?

Comment: Try using the full path for the file, rather than relative.

Comment: @Andrew nothing works it does nothing

Comment: @RimonKhan thanks but didnt work

Comment: @RossWilson exports is in public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you not going to be getting any output from this is because it `file_exists('exports')` is going to return false.

Try adding the absolute path instead:

```
$folderName = public_path('exports');
```

Also, just for good measure and to check this is correct add an `else` to output something if the directory doesn't exist.

Hope this helps!